# Greatest of three random variables

Tags: probability

Assume that we have $3$ not equal random variables $(A, B, C)$. If we know that 
$$Pr(A>B)=x, \quad  Pr(A>C)=y, \quad Pr(B>C)=z$$ 
What is $Pr(A$ is the greatest one)?

I know that $Pr(A$ is the greatest one) is equal to $Pr(A>B, A>C)$. So I need to calculate $Pr(A>C| A>B)$. Could you please guide me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have enough information.  We can calculate the chance $C$ is least is $yz$, the chance $C$ is greatest is $(1-y)(1-z)=1-y-z+yz$ and the chance $C$ is middle is $y+z-yz$.  If we assume the $A$ vs $B$ chance is independent of where $C$ is in the order, the chance $A$ is greatest is $x(y+z-yz)$ from $A \gt B$ and $C$ not largest, but there could be correlations.  We could have that $A \gt B$ whenever $C$ is largest, which would lower the chance $A$ is largest.  Nothing prohibits that as far as I can see.

Added:  There are six possible orders.  Let the chance of $ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA$ be $a,b,c,d,e,f$ respectively.  We are given $a+b+e=x,a+b+c=y,a+c+d=z,a+b+c+d+e+f=1$ and are asked for $a+b$.  This would work if we could find a proper linear combination, but I can't.  $P(A \gt C|A\gt B)=\frac {a+b}{a+b+e}=\frac{a+b}x$, but I can't get $a+b$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Lets try it. assume that A can be 2,3, and 8. B can be 5,6, and 9. C can be 1, 4, and 7. So x=2/9, y=5/9, and z=7/9. Then the probability that C is the least is not yz. Since yz=35/81 while the probability of C is least is 13/27. Is it correct?

Comment: I was definitely assuming $B\gt C$ and $A \gt C$ were independent.  Probably I shouldn't, given the worry later on.  I didn't check your numbers, but in a case like this there are correlations that make it not be $yz$

Comment: Yes you are right. Maybe, when we know pr(A>B), then pr(B>C) and pr (A>C) are not independent !!! anyway, thank you so much Ross.

Comment: @Ross: If you could make calculations for $C$ then you could make similar calculations for $A$.  But you cannot do either without more information.

Comment: What more info do i need? I know  that pr(A is greatest)=pr(A>B and A>C)= pr(A>B)*pr(A>C if A>B). What info do I need to calculate pr(A>C if A>B)?

Comment: @ Ross: Thank you for additional explanation. I am completely understood now

Comment: @ Ross: The point is that we can't say that a=pr(A>B).pr(B>C)